# Грамматическое построение, пунктуация и схема предложения

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, сложное-предложение

**Я думаю, что это то же самое, что и прошлый альбом, только немного мягче и с другими словами.**
Правильно ли построено предложение, верна ли пунктуация?
Не могу схему "нарисовать" к нему. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что содержание то же самое, что и в последнем альбоме, только немного мягче и с другими словами.

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, сказуемое в придаточном распространенное (составное именное)  - "то же самое, что и в последнем альбоме, только немного мягче и с другими словами.

Именная часть включает указательное местоимение, сравнительный оборот и несогласованный оборот ("только немного мягче и с другими словами").

Answer (score 2):

Грамматически построение верное, ошибки нет. Схема такова:

```
[ -  =], (что ).
```

Если нужна подробная схема с указанием осложняющих членов, то:

[ -  =], (что  -  =  ,_ .*.*.сравнит.оборот, только  = и =).

это - подлеж.

то же самое,только  мягче и с другими словами- однородные сказуемые,

что и прошлый альбом - сравнит. оборот  .

Answer (score 1):

***Это то же самое, что  и прошлый альбом.***

Розенталь и Добромыслов *("Трудные вопросы грамматики и правописания", М., 1960)* о подобных предложениях когда-то писали так:

> Для выяснения синтаксических функций сочетаний, присоединяемых
>   посредством сравнительного союза… мы исходим из структуры остальной
>   части предложения, а именно:
>
> …**если** **сказуемое** в ней **выражено указательным местоимением**, то сочетание
>   с союзом является **придаточным** сказуемым.

И предложение *"Вы для меня то же, что родной сын"* (очень близкое по структуре к разбираемому нами) они характеризовали так:

> Предложение является **сложноподчинённым** с придаточным сказуемым: в
>   главном предложении *(Вы для меня то же)* сказуемое выражается
>   указательным местоимением ***то*** (с частицей же), лишённым
>   конкретного значения, для раскрытия которого используется
>   **придаточное**  *что родной сын*.

***Я думаю, что это то же самое, что и прошлый альбом, только немного мягче и с другими словами.***

Руководствуясь мнением Розенталя и Добромыслова (поскольку в современных учебниках разбора подобных предложений мне найти не удалось), я бы схему этого предложения нарисовал так:

**[ -  =], (что… ), (что… )**

==================================

**P.S.**

> *Я думаю, что содержание то же самое, **что и в последнем альбоме**, только немного мягче и с другими словами.*

В этом предложении выделенная жирным часть **не сравнительный оборот, а придаточное**, поскольку в ней есть обстоятельство *"в последнем альбоме"*, указывающее на пропуск сказуемого:

*Я думаю, что содержание то же самое, **что [было] и в последнем альбоме**, только немного мягче и с другими словами.*

Схема:

**[ -  =], (что… ), (что… )**

Answer (score 0):

Структура предложения правильная, семантика понятна, пунктуация тоже верна.